# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1) Mapbox react native

Tags: react-native, mapbox

I am trying to get current position on Mapbox, but I am getting a unhandled promise (TypeError: null is not an object) on the return of the method. I believe its caused by trying to grab info before iOS user allows permission, but not sure how to make function await user permissions. Its failing at `const currentCoords = [location.coords.longitude, location.coords.latitude]`

```
return (
      <View style={styles.page}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <mapbox.MapView style={styles.map} />
          <mapbox.UserLocation
            onUpdate={(location) => {
              const currentCoords = [
                location.coords.longitude,
                location.coords.latitude,
              ];
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are likely getting the `null is not an object` because of either `location` or `location.coords` being null.

Rather than awaiting permissions, you can simply add a null check to ensure that the returned values are not null.

```
  <mapbox.UserLocation
    onUpdate={(location) => {
      if(!location || !location.coords) return;

      const currentCoords = [
        location.coords.longitude,
        location.coords.latitude,
      ];
    }}
  />
```

Comment: Thanks. That seemed to do the trick. Is there a way I can recall this code because it failed?

Comment: It should automatically be called again once the user location changes. It might get called on permission change as well. You'll have to see if it does. If it doesn't get called, you should be able to listen to permission change and manually get geolocation to do the same work that you do in the callback.